# What's the difference between "left top" and "top left" in jquery ui position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

What's the difference between the following two postion setting?

Setting 1：(easy to understand)

```
$("#myinput").autocomplete({
    source: myArray,
    position: { my: "**left top**", at: "right top" }
});
```

Setting 2: (confusing)

```
$("#myinput").autocomplete({
    source: myArray,
    position: { my: "**top left**", at: "right top" }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this diagram](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#tips) for a detailed view:

[image]

Comment: is this combination "`position: { my: "top left", at: "right top" }`" valid? seems it is not one of the 13 combinations on the site.

Comment: have you test it? my testing indicates that: `position: { my: "center", at: "center" }`, `position: { my: "bottom left", at: "top left" }`, `position: { my: "bottom center", at: "top center" }`, `position: { my: "bottom right", at: "top right"}`, `position: { my: "top right", at: "bottom right"}`, `position: { my: "top center", at: "bottom center"}`, `position: { my: "top left", at: "bottom left" }` have the same effect. Am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: the link is dead but the diagram helped me understand my vs at options.
http://qtip2.com/demos#section-positioning

Answer (score 1):

According tot he [jQuery UI docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position):

> Defines which position on the element being positioned to align with
>   the target element: "horizontal vertical" alignment.

So your first example would be left horizontally, top vertically while your second example would be top horizontally and left vertically.